# Getting Null Pointer Exp when i pass Data from activity to activity

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

```
"questions": [
        {
            "number": 1,
            "text": "How many principles are there for plant distribution ?",
            "options": [
                {
                    "number": 1,
                    "text": "2",
                    "mark": 0
                },
                {
                    "number": 2,
                    "text": "4",
                    "mark": 0
                },
                {
                    "number": 3,
                    "text": "8",
                    "mark": 1
                },
                {
                    "number": 4,
                    "text": "16",
                    "mark": 0
                }
            ],
            "isMultiChoice": null
        },{
        "number": 1,
        "text": "How many principles are there for plant distribution ?",
        "options": [
            {
                "number": 1,
                "text": "2",
                "mark": 0
            },
            {
                "number": 2,
                "text": "4",
                "mark": 0
            },
            {
                "number": 3,
                "text": "8",
                "mark": 1
            },
            {
                "number": 4,
                "text": "16",
                "mark": 0
            }
        ],
        "isMultiChoice": null
    }]
```

Here is how i am tacking options

```
optionsList = questionsList.get(question).getOptions();
```

But I am getting this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
> 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3507)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3661)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:140)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:100)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2232)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:238)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7824)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:981)
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object
> reference

Can u please help me from this

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
questionsList = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("questionsData");
```

in this way i am tacking question list.
i am able to read questions. but i am not able to read answer.
Can u help me

Answer (score 0):

From First Activity Use

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("questionsData", questionsArrayList);
```

In Second Activity Use

```
questionsList = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("questionsData");
```